# Not able to include component in two different modules in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Not able to include component in two different modules in angular where one module is developed by lazyload feature.

A sample project is in github, here is the link : 
https://github.com/Gdharbc/angularLazyLoad

Please can anyone look into it and help me out in resolving it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the component into a ***sharedModule*** and load the **`sharedModule`** in each component. That is the way to go!

For example create a component inside the sharedModule,

```
import { SidebarWidget } from '../shared/components/sidebar_widget/sidebar.component';

@NgModule({
 imports :[],
 declarations: [SidebarWidget],
 providers : [],
 entryComponents:[]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tried with that approach, but the links are not working if i do that way. You can take a look at my code which is there in the above github link.

Comment: what do you mean by link?

Comment: where i have committed the code in github, you can take a look into the code.https://github.com/Gdharbc/angularLazyLoad